# Cannot import ScrapinghubClient

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapinghub

```
>>> from scrapinghub import ScrapinghubClient
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ImportError: cannot import name ScrapinghubClient

---

Why is this happening?
I have Python 2.7.13 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, May 11 2017, 13:17:26) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Comment: please share all traceback

Comment: Did you [install it](http://python-scrapinghub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#installation)? If yes, how?

Comment: Make sure you use v2.0

Comment: I was using an earlier version. Than you so much!